# jsp caching tag library

Tags: java, jsp, caching, tld

I want to cache some portions of my JSP page because it is heavy to render. The whole page cannot be cached as it contains user specific content, but most of it can. I thought the best solution would be to create a JSP cache tag. It seems there are several solutions for that but most of these projects are dead or abandoned

http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/
http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/cache-doc/
http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/cachetag.htm

I am wondering if there is any project that is alive, open source, or is there any better soltion that can work?

Answer (score 1):

OSCache has not been abandoned; a lack of constant change only means that it fulfills the requirements the designers had, not that the project isn't useful any more.

Comment: To me it seems the project is dead, at least the website says so http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/

Comment: The project itself is still fully functional. YMMV.